# Ensuring a function runs after setState

Tags: reactjs

I know that SetState takes a callback, which I´m using. For some reason, though, it is not running after the state updates. Am I doing something wrong?

```
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
          [name]: event.target.value
        });
          if(event.target.value.length > 1) {
          this.getSuggestions();
          this.setState({
          query: event.target.value,
        }, () => this.getCoordinates)
      }

getCoordinates = () =>{
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( {"address":this.state.query}, this.onSuccessGetAddress)
  }
```

Comment: Why two seperate calls to setState?

Comment: There are two inputs which update different things. The second one has a validation (has to  be longer than 1 character)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You provided a callback which returns the function `this.getCoordinates`:

```
() => this.getCoordinates
```

You want to provide a callback which calls `this.getCoordinates`:

```
() => this.getCoordinates()
```

or

```
this.getCoordinates
```

Comment: How is the last  one different from the one that´s written already?

Comment: The last one passes the function as reference to be executed, your version passes a function that returns your function but that never gets called afterwards.

Comment: The last one is equivalent to `() => { const geocoder ... }` (exactly as you defined) which only needs to be called once to execute the inner code.  That means yours is equivalent to `() => () => { const geocoder ... }`, which needs to be 'called twice' to execute the inner code.